# Uncompressing C# WebResponse & DeSerializing it

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, rest, deserialization

I am talking to a web API to get response data for

**https://api.transport.nsw.gov.au/v1/gtfs/schedule/ferries**

it is based on protobuf schema

`string authorization = "apikey *******************";`

**So, if you want to try it you can either create a free API key or use the SAMPLE zipped file I get and try to decompress or deserialize it using C#**

Sample code is at:this [link](http://www.mediafire.com/file/8fib27mg7b8fkda/response.zip)

I can get the web response stream, and when I do it using Postman and download it as a "zipped" file, when I uncompress the file, I get a lot of XML files that has the data I am looking, but when trying to do so with code, I always get errors, tried many methods, one of them is the below

```
FeedMessage feed = DeserializeCompressed<FeedMessage>(webResponse.GetResponseStream());

 public static T DeserializeCompressed<T>(Stream stream, JsonSerializerSettings settings = null)
        {
            using (var compressor = new GZipStream(stream, CompressionMode.Decompress))
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(compressor))
            using (var jsonReader = new JsonTextReader(reader))
            {
                var serializer = JsonSerializer.CreateDefault(settings);
                return serializer.Deserialize<T>(jsonReader);
            }
        }
```

I want to know how uncompress this zip file stream and de-serialize it into strong typed C# classes

Comment: Kindly update your question with what you have done. This is incomplete.

Comment: I wont give you the authenticaiton indeed, you can try creating an API key it is for free, or you can help me in saying how to decompress/deserialize a web response, its that simple, it has nothing to do with the URL !!!

Comment: Sample of ZIPPED file getting from response is can you decompress it and deserialize it using C# ? http://www.mediafire.com/file/8fib27mg7b8fkda/response.zip

Answer (score 0):

Few points

- Are you getting data in compressed format? I think no.
- If not,then, Why are you trying to compress and decompress the data
  at your end? Is this a business requirement?

BTW,Your code needs a class of Type T.

```
public static T DeserializeCompressed<T>(Stream stream, JsonSerializerSettings settings = null)
{
   using (var compressor = new GZipStream(stream, CompressionMode.Decompress))
   using (var reader = new StreamReader(compressor))
   using (var jsonReader = new JsonTextReader(reader))
   {
      var serializer = JsonSerializer.CreateDefault(settings);
       return serializer.Deserialize<T>(jsonReader);
   }
}
```

So your usage will be something like this
var obj = DeserializeCompressed(yourStream,jsonparam);

In order to make above working you a class for the same. Your api url gave me this output.

`{ "ErrorDetails":{ "TransactionId":"000001543eb7b14f-2fcea63", "ErrorDateTime":"2016-10-19T17:03:58.284+11:00", "Message":"The calling application is unauthenticated.", "RequestedUrl":"/v1/gtfs/schedule/ferries", "RequestMethod":"GET" } }`

So If I want to use this  in my app first I will need a class. That is shown below. And you can generate it very easily using http://json2csharp.com/.

### Class

```
public class ErrorDetails
{
    public string TransactionId { get; set; }
    public string ErrorDateTime { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public string RequestedUrl { get; set; }
    public string RequestMethod { get; set; }
}
```

Let me know if it is of any help. I know, this is not the actual stuff that you need, but this will help you in moving ahead.

Comment: if you checked the URL posted, I am trying to consume an API that return a web response compressed in ZIP file and I need to uncompress then desalinize it. what you posted honestly is totally unrelated to my question

Comment: @KarimKamel The url that you gave , needs authentication and that JSOn was the output of the same. And the solution is just a way to do so. Thats it. Actually your question is incomplete. You have just shown us the method that you are using to deserialize the object but not its usage. So based on what you have in your question, its not irrelevant. Kindly update your question first with what you are doing. Thanks

Comment: I wont give you the authenticaiton indeed, you can try creating an API key it is for free, or you can help me in saying how to decompress/deserialize a web response, its that simple, it has nothing to do with the URL !!!

Comment: Sample of ZIPPED file getting from response is can you decompress it and deserialize it using C# ? mediafire.com/file/8fib27mg7b8fkda/response.zip

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to solve it 
 **First**  
 **Download** 

https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/

 or  **Install**  using NugGet Manager

```
Install-Package CsvHelper
```

seems out the solution is to unzip the file using ZIPArchive class

```
using (ZipArchive archive = new ZipArchive(webResponse.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    foreach (ZipArchiveEntry entry in archive.Entries)
                    {
                        Stream s = entry.Open();
                        var sr = new StreamReader(s);
                        var myStr = sr.ReadToEnd();
                    }
                }
```